# My java code is error because of incomparable types

Tags: java, arrays

My java code is error because of incomparable types.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Hello {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
          Scanner listScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
          while (listScanner.hasNext()) {
            arrayList.add(listScanner.next());
          }
          System.out.println("List " + arrayList);
          break;
        }
        Scanner lestScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
        while (lestScanner.hasNext()) {
          arrayList.add(lestScanner.next());
        }
        for (int i = arrayList.size(); i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
          if (lestScanner == arrayList.size()) {
            System.out.println("Exist: ");
          } else if (lestScanner != arrayList.size()) {
            System.out.println("Null: ");
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: whya are you doing `Scanner listScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());` ?

Comment: to input a list of array then to check if its null or exist by inputting another data

Comment: I think you need to read how Scanner works.

Answer (score -1):

lestScanner : It is Scanner class Object                       -It is in Object form

arrayList.size(): It gives the arrayList size (returns number) - It is in int form

Error occured at this line 25: stScanner == arrayList.size

Here you are checking scanner class object  with arrayList size  ,That's why your getting 
 Incompatible error.
 please  tell your exact requirement

Comment: i just wanna check if it is null or not on my array list i just inputted

Comment: if you want to check whether lestScanner  is null or not. Use this condition 
  if(lestScanner == null) or lestScanner.equals(null)

Comment: You can use isEmpty()  method for arrayList to check whether array list is empty or not.  boolean flag= arrayList.isEmpty(); . It returns true is arrayList is empty and it it returns false if arrayList is not empty